# Need help displaying the same listbox item info from different listboxes vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, listbox

In my current project, I am making a card game. Basically how it works is I have one listbox called "lstdeck". This is where you find all of the cards. The second is called "lsthand". This is your hand that is created when 5 cards are taken out of the "lstdeck" and put into your "lsthand".

When a card is selected from either listbox (deck or hand), the cards information should be displayed in "txtdescription". However I cannot figure out how to have multiple listbox.selecteditem call the same Boolean. Here's a snippet of what I hoped would work but failed me.

```
Dim CurrentList as string
Private Sub lsthand_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lsthand.SelectedIndexChanged
    Currentlist = "lsthand"
    CheckCards()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckCards()
    Dim FindSelection As String = ".selecteditem"
    If Currentlist & FindSelection = "Face Card 1" Then
       txtdescription.text = "This is the first face card."
```

In the instance above, the card named "Face Card 1" (displayed in listbox) is selected. It should not matter which listbox it is in. In hopes of adding two strings, one being "lsthand" and one ".selecteditem", the outcome would be: "lsthand.selecteditem". Unfortunately, this did not work. Does anybody know a solution to this?

Also, I realize I could make a "lstdeck.selecteditem" Private sub to check just that listbox, and one for the "lsthand". But i am using about 180 different cards and 6 listboxes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My first thought: How do you handle the 180 cards?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a sub that handles all the `SelectedIndexChanged` .

I think you want somethine like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(New String() {"dog", "cat", "rabbit", "tux"})
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(New String() {"earth", "fire", "water", "air"})
    ListBox3.Items.AddRange(New String() {"Green Day", "Limp Bizkit", "Donots", "Guano Apes"})
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged, ListBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
    If DirectCast(sender, ListBox).SelectedItem = "cat" Then
        MsgBox("best animal!")
    Else
        MsgBox("something else...")
    End If
End Sub
```